# How to loop through array of objects in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to loop through an array of objects inside of Firebase, in my case I'm trying to access the data in stats, and I'm not sure how to access that value, I'm trying to use map but its giving me an error saying:

> cannot read property map of undefined

Code:

```
// Champs
// -LIvNqyUt8Bsvrspears
// id:
// "-LIvNqyUt8Bsvrspears"
// img:
// "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/leagueofleg..."
// img2:
// "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB..."
// name:
// "Ronaldo"
//     Stats
//        lvl: "medium"
//        "win rate ": "51%"

// Team: "real madrid"

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ChampsRef, timeRef } from "./reference";
import { getsinglechamp } from "../actions/champs";
import { connect } from "react-redux"; // this is not being used.  oh isee so like this?
import { Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";
class OneChamp extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    weak: [],
    img: ""
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const { dispatch, match } = this.props;
    dispatch(getsinglechamp(match.params.id));
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.champ);
    const { dispatch, loading } = this.props;
    console.log("change", this.props);
    console.log(this.props.champ.stats);
    let content = null;
    if (loading) {
      content = <p>Loading...</p>;
    } else {
      content = (
        <div>
          <div>
            <h1>{this.props.champ.name}</h1>
            <img src={this.props.champ.img} height="80px" />
          </div>

          <br />

          <ul>
            {this.props.champ.stats.map(stats => (
              <div>
                <li>{stats.lvl} </li>
              </div>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return <div>{content}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("champs", state.champs);
  console.log(state.loading);
  return {
    champ: state.champs.champ,
    loading: state.loading
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(OneChamp);
```

Comment: What are you getting when doing this `console.log(this.props.champ.stats);`. Do you get an array or object?

Comment: yes i get an object

Comment: and its saying that map is not a function

Comment: Try this `Object.keys(this.props.champ.stats).map(stats =>.....`

Comment: yup that worked, thanks!

Comment: so map doesnt work on objects?

Comment: No, it's for arrays

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain without seeing how you initialize `this.props.champ.stats`, but my guess is that this is a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) you get from the Firebase Database.

While a `DataSnapshot` may look like an array at a glance, it does not implement `Array.map()`. It *does* however implement `forEach()` so you could use *that* to loop over the items, and then render each individually to HTML.